# Why would jQuery UI Layout run so slow in Adobe AIR?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, air

I've been reworking an app for a long while now and I just got it to work on AIR. However, the common UI layout plugin ( http://layout.jquery-dev.net/downloads.cfm ) slows down the app to a practical standstill.

It's over 5 thousand lines so I don't expect anyone to debug anything, but has anyone run into this? I'm using AIR just as a wrapper with an iframe pointing to my site. It's bizarre that simply running it from the iframe is making things so slow.

With the plugin off the app clearly doesn't look right at all but everything runs smooth again. Even CSS hover states are slow with it on so something is clobbering AIR.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS! Yeah that's the answer. If you use advanced CSS like box-shadows, or other expensive rules, the AIR engine is so slow it will slow down your app.

Using layout made the problem worse since it adds and removes classes on mouseenter and leave. Adding and removing those classes forced re-rendering, which was horribly slow and made the app chug to a near-standstill.

At least in my example we were able to get away with just cutting out box-shadows while leaving in other rules like gradients.